# Computer Modern Bright font and blackboard bold symbols

Tags: fonts, sans-serif, blackboard

I am trying to match the sans serif math font provided by `cmbright` with proper blackboard bold symbols (also sans serif). I found that the `fourier` and `stix` (`xits`?) fonts provide such symbols. But how can I use `cmbright` and import only the blackboard bold symbols in LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mathalfa` package makes this kind of changes quite easy!

For `fourier`:

```
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage[bb=fourier]{mathalfa} % esstix math bb font
```

For `stix` (resp. `esstix`):

```
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage[bb=esstix]{mathalfa} % fourier math bb font
```

Answer (score 5):

Getting the definition of the font from `fourier` is easy; with a little trial and error one can also get the right magnification factor.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cmbright}

%%% taken from fourier.sty
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{futm}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{futm}{m}{n}{
  <-> s * [.97534] fourier-bb % but changing the magnification factor
  }{}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{futm}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
$-3\in\mathbb{Z}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}\ne Q$

\texttt{\sbox0{$Q$}\the\ht0}

\texttt{\sbox0{$\mathbb{Q}$}\the\ht0}

\end{document}
```

The last two lines show that the heights match (up to 0.00001pt).

[image]

For the STIX fonts the procedure is similar.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cmbright}

%% taken from the STIX font distribution
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontFamily{LS1}{stixbb}{\skewchar\font127 }
\DeclareFontShape{LS1}{stixbb}{m}{n} {<-> s*[1.032631] stix-mathbb}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LS1}{stixbb}{b}{n} {<-> s*[1.032631] stix-mathbb-bold}{}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{LS1}{stixbb}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{bold}{LS1}{stixbb}{b}{n}

\begin{document}
$-3\in\mathbb{Z}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}\ne Q$

\texttt{\sbox0{$Q$}\the\ht0}

\texttt{\sbox0{$\mathbb{Q}$}\the\ht0}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works for me for the `fourier` fonts, but for the `stix` fonts it say `LaTeX Error: This NFSS system isn't set up properly.` Am I missing somestig?

Comment: @porst17 I just copied from my file.

Comment: What's the name of the file? Maybe mine is different (TeXLive 2012) or even absent.